# How to access the task_struct behind a process not currently running?

Tags: linux, process, kernel, task

I'm researching an alternate way to manage sleeping processes, and for my experiment I need to make a modified Linux kernel. For what I'm making, I need to have access to the task_struct that describes a process, even if it's the currently running one. I need to do this so that I can update the fields of a task_struct for my proposed method of sleeping.

TL;DR How do I access the task_struct of a process that's not currently running on the CPU. I would know it's PID.

Comment: What do you mean by "How to access"? Do you want to **find** `task_struct` for a specific process? If so, what kind of information (name, pid, etc.) about the process do you know? Or do you know `task_struct` of a process, but ask about what kind of **synchronization** you need to use when accessing the fields of this struct? In some cases, it is sufficient to hold RCU lock (`rcu_read_lock()`) when read fields of the process. But in other cases you need other kind of syncrhonization. Plese, make the question **more specific**; currently it is **unclear** what do you have and what do you want.

Comment: @alinsoar: Not sure what do you mean by the comment "off topic for C programming" when you remove "C" tag. The Linux kernel is written in C, and the question is (probably) about the C function/macro which does the needed work. Whether the question itself contains C code or not is unrelated to the tag's needs.

Comment: @Tsyvarev his question has 95% specific of Linux and 5 procent specific of C. Galois theory is also implemented in C in cryptographic libraries, but it makes no sense to ask Galois questions here.

Comment: @alinsoar: But the question is not about *abstract* theory or algorithms. It is about Linux kernel which is **mainly implemented** in C. Some knowledge of C is needed for understand the question and possible answers. Much more knowledge of C is needed for find and write the answer on a question about Linux kernel. I would revert the "C" tag, but only after the question becomes clear.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the question is not clear here because it has no link with C.  It is for #linux topic.

Comment: @alinsoar: The question is not clear because it is not clear :) I fully understand the topic on which the question is asked - "linux-kernel" is my 3d top tag and my search tag.

Comment: @Tsyvarev from the viewpoint of a C programmer it is even 90% less clear.

Comment: Yes, I saw "C" tag as your top tag. I agree with you in that the question requires more "linux-kernel" knowledge than a "C" one. But this doesn't mean that the question should have the only tag "linux-kernel". And I think that "C" tag is also applicable for the question. Yes, solely knowledge of "C" is insufficient for understand the question. But this is not required from the tags. Even within my favorite tags I regularly find questions which I don't understand because I lack knowledge in some other topic. But I remove my tags from the questions which have no relation with that tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[find_task_by_vpid() in sched.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1.10/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1602) (assuming recent kernel).

As mentioned by @Tsyvarev, there are (a lot of) synchronization issues to solve before you can call it, so learn what its callers do so that you don't shoot yourself in the foot.